# Using latest TiledMap, how do you get a specific tile from x and y index?

Tags: collision-detection, libgdx, tilemap

Seems basic enough, but I can't seem to find the answer: I am trying to implement collission detecton and for that I need the properties of the tile the player is currently entering. I am using `gdx.maps.tiles.TiledMap`, which does not have a `getCell(int x, int y)` like the older TileMap had. Any help on this specific issue or just some general advice on how to do this will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the new libGDX tiled maps implementation, you need to request the concerned layer before being able to request for a particular tile.

So:

```
TiledMapTileLayer layer = (TiledMapTileLayer) currentMap.getLayers().get("layer_id");
```

And then i can do:

```
layer.getCell(x, y);
```

Which will return a `Cell` instance.

Here is the new documentation about tile maps: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Tile-maps

Comment: Thank you very much! I did already use layers, but I didn't use the cast, which was the problem.